# Error in value entered by Update

Tags: sql, vba, excel

The update is executed correctly, however the value that is inserted not table is different from the value informed in the query.

I'm using excel 2013, and I would like to understand why this happens

I think it's some kind of formatting

o resultado do update é: 0 (zero)

```
                        Function ExecutaSQl(sSQL As String, _
                                       Optional wb As Workbook)
                        'Faz uma consulta SQL e num intervalo, numa Planilha chamada wsTemp.
                        'Se bTemCabeçalho = True, significa que os cabeçalhos serão gravados no intervalo ou variant de saída.
                        'Se bApagarCampos = True, o intervalo de largura igual ao número de recordsets de saída serão apagados
                        'pelo método ClearContents.
                        'Para funcionar, é necessário adicionar a referência Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 ou superior

                            Dim lng As Long
                            Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
                            Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
                            'Dim lista

                            Set rs = Nothing
                            Set cn = Nothing


                            Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
                            Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


                            If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

                            'Aqui cria-se a cadeia de conexão. Note que ela pode
                            'variar em função da versão do Excel utilizado:
                            If Application.Version < 12 Then
                                cn.ConnectionString = _
                                  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                                  "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & ";" & _
                                  "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
                            Else
                                cn.ConnectionString = _
                                  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                  "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & ";" & _
                                  "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
                            End If
                            cn.Open 'Abre a conexão

                            Set rs = cn.Execute(sSQL)

                        End Function

                    Sub Definir_Notas_VG()

                        Dim sSQL As String

                        Dim Inicio As Double



                        Inicio = Now

                        sSQL = "Update [Base_Fat$] as T " & _
                        "LEFT Join [BASE_LANCAMENTO$] AS L " & _
                        "ON T.[COD_ITEM] = L.[COD] " & _
                        "Set T.[VENDA_GARANTIDA] = 'SIM' " & _
                        "Where " & _
                        "((T.[EMISSAO] <= " & Format(DateSerial(2017, 4, 1), "0") & " " & _
                        "AND T.[CLASSIFICACAO_PEDIDO_DESCRICAO] = 'LANÇAMENTO                    ') " & _
                        "OR (T.CLASSIFICACAO_PEDIDO_DESCRICAO = 'VENDA GARANTIDA               ')) " & _
                        "OR (T.[EMISSAO]>=L.[DATA_INICIO] AND T.[EMISSAO]<=L.[DATA_LIMITE])"

                        ExecutaSQl sSQL

                        MsgBox ("Tempo de duração: " & Format(Now - Inicio, "hh:mm:ss"))

                    End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps re-create your update statement as a select statement and check the results.

Comment: A selection works

However this command:
Set T. [SALAR_GARANTIDA] = 'YES'

Set does not work ...

The function registers in the correct places of the table, but registers the wrong one

Comment: Have you tried setting it to 'YES' or TRUE instead of 'SIM'?

Comment: I have tried, when I set true, the value registered to 0 as well

Comment: Try Set T.[VENDA_GARANTIDA]=1

Comment: Or: Set T.[VENDA_GARANTIDA] = -1

Comment: I changed it to 1 and -1 but I record the same information, I'm seeing some tutorials can be problem in the connection. something like that:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsm;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES";
But I could not make it work

Comment: I discovered the problem, the query understands that the column T. [SALAR_GARANTIDA] is a date column, so I do not allow text or integer values.